# Retrofit POST. Add JSON parameter to every post request

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I have four static parameters which i need to set to every post retrofit request only once, because i don't need to put them with every request every time. This is my code:

```
  public interface Login {
        @POST("login")
        @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
        Call<String> login(@Body JsonObject json);
    }
```

then i call it and pass email and password as body parameters like this:

```
  private void sendLoginRequest() {
    API.login().login(CommandLogin.getInputParamsAsJSON(mStrEmail, Utils.md5(mStrPassword))).enqueue(this);
}
```

then in **intercept** body i tried to pass this static parameters, but when i check the **log** it seems to pass only this two static params without email and password. In my situation i want to put in **body** **email**,**password**,**os**,**version**.

```
public class API {

private static <T> T builder(Class<T> endpoint) {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(
                    new Interceptor() {
                        @Override
                        public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain){
                            try {
                                Request original = chain.request();

                                JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
                                params.put("version"        , "6");
                                params.put("os"             , "2");

                                MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
                                RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, params.toString());

                                Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                                        .post(body);

                                Request request = requestBuilder.build();

                                return chain.proceed(request);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            //TODO
                            return null;
                        }
                    })
            .addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
            .build();

    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Utils.BASE_COMPONENT_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
            .create(endpoint);
}



public static Login login() {
    return builder(Login.class);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because, you are basically overwriting original Login Post Request Body with new params. What you should do instead is, get the post body from original request and append new params to it.

**Something like below (code not tested)**

```
try {
    // Create new buffer
    final Buffer buffer = new Buffer();

    // Copy original request's json body to buffer
    chain.request().body().writeTo(buffer);

    // Convert buffer to JSONObject
    JSONObject params = new JSONObject(buffer.readUtf8());

    // Append new params
    params.put("version", "6");
    params.put("os", "2");

    // Now the params json object will have all 4 values: email,password,os,version

    // TODO: Your remaining code

} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.d("Login","Error creating post body", ex);
}
```